# Lagrange Optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

I would like to ask for the optimization problem:

$$\max_{x,y} g(x,y)$$

st. $x+y=1$

Would there be any difference if we formulate the problem as:

$$g(x,y) + \lambda(1-x-y)$$

as opposed to

$$g(x,y) + \lambda(x+y-1) \text{?}$$

Thanks!

Comment: When you write \max_{x,y} g(x,y), you see this: $$\max_{x,y} g(x,y)$$ But when you write max_{x,y} g(x,y) with no backslash, you see this: $$max_{x,y} g(x,y)$$ (And you added some white space manually.) The former is standard usage and I changed it.  (When its inline rather than displayed, then it looks like this: $\max_{x,y} g(x,y)$). MathJax uses a system based on what TeX uses, and TeX was introduced in the '80s by the legendary Donald Knuth, not by an illiterate, so it is capable of standard things. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference because we allow $\lambda$ to be positive, negative or zero.

Comment: what about the KKT-conditions which require >0?

Comment: @Ben: First the KKT-conditions require $\ge 0$. Second, the above is not using KKT-conditions since the constraint is an *equality*. It is just a simple Lagrangian. Of course, you can also use the KKT machinery but then you have two inequalities  $x+y\le 1$ and $-x-y\le -1$ and two multipliers, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ which of course must be non-negative but this is a rather cumbersome way to deal with equality constraints.

Comment: @Ben: Using the KKT approach, the FOC conditions both with respect to x and y will have a term that is $\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ which is equivalent to the original $\lambda$, which can be positive, negative or zero.